# android onMessageReceived broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Sendbroadcast is not working in my code.

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            String tit = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
          
            Log.d("title, body", tit);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("title", tit);
            intent.putExtra("body", body);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    }
```

OnMessageReceived does not work after sendbroadcast (intent)

```
private BroadcastReceiver fcmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(@Nullable Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            String tit = extras.getString("title");
            String body = extras.getString("body");

            Comm.fcmTit = tit;
            Comm.fcmBody = body;

            getPush("receive");

        }
    };
```

I would like to receive data by overrideing onReceive in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Use `LocalBroadcastManager` and make sure that you have registered your broadcast in `onResume` function

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("messageReceiver"));
```

& send broadcast like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("messageReceiver");
intent.putExtra("title", tit);
intent.putExtra("body", body);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Can't we use a broadcast receiver instead of a LocalBroadcastManager?

Comment: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.